# How do you post back to the controller from an icons onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

Project type: ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application.

I'm trying to post back to the controller when the check-circle icon is clicked, but I'm getting an error because the action is decorated with `HttpPost`. When I change it to `HttpGet`, the error goes away.

How do I get it to post back?

```
<span id="confirmDeleteSpan_@item.UserID.ToString()" style="display:none">
    <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Delete?</span>
    <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "ManageUsers", new { Id = @item.UserID})'" data-for></i>
    <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" onclick="confirmDelete('@item.UserID.ToString()', false)"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps but it may not

```
<button onclick="confirmDelete('@item.UserID.ToString()', false)"> <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i> </button>
```

or

```
<button class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" onclick="confirmDelete('@item.UserID.ToString()', false)"></button>
```